# how can open a page, call a function, then open another page using PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I know different variations of this question exist because I've spent hours looking for examples. Basically my script has 3 links that I want to open, wait if the content that I'm looking for exists in the page then save the page's HTML locally. Then do the exact same thing for the second and third link. My code is below

```
    var system = require('system')
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    var fs = require('fs');
    var wd = 'mylocaldir'
    var url1 = '1st url link'
    var url2 = '2nd url link'
    var url3 = '3rd url link'
    var file1 = 'url1.html'
    var file2 = 'url2.html'
    var file3 = 'url3.html'
    page.open(url1, function() {
         //do {phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.evaluate(function() {return !document.querySelectorAll(".centercontent").length > 0} ))
        fs.write(file1, page.content, 'w');
        page.open(url2, function() {
            //do {phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.evaluate(function() {return !document.querySelectorAll(".centercontent").length > 0} ))
            fs.write(file2, page.content, 'w');
            page.open(url3, function(){
                //do {phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.evaluate(function() {return !document.querySelectorAll(".centercontent").length > 0} ))
               fs.write(file3, page.content, 'w');
               var cookies = JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies);
               fs.write("cookies.txt", cookies, 644)
            });

       });

    });
    phantom.exit()
```

I was hoping that the do-while loop would send a mouse event until the content that I wanted returned true but it's not working like I hoped it would. Actually it doesn't seem like the page even opens, and none of the page's HTML gets saved. I'm specifically looking for a way to structure this script so that for each url link, phantomjs will open the link, wait for `page.evaluate(function() {return !document.querySelectorAll(".centercontent").length > 0} ))` to return true, save the page's HTML locally and then do the same for the next two url links.

How can I open a page, wait for this specific condition `page.evaluate(function() {return !document.querySelectorAll(".centercontent").length > 0} ))` to return true, save page locally, then repeat that process for another page that I wish to open in the same session ?

Comment: Currently it's unclear what you're specifically asking. Please, edit your post for clarity and state the question. To save session cookies use `--cookies-file=cookies.txt` command-line argument: `phantomjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt script.js`